# How to set hint visibility true for editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

Currently I am working on EditText Hint. Actually I have number of EditText fields and TextView fields. Basic working of the app is text view data is drag and drop in edit text field. But during this time when data is entered into edit text field the colour of the edit text field should change and instead of showing entered text it should show the hint and visibility should gone for entered text.

I already tried with focusListener with CustomEditText class on edit text field but it isn't working. When user drag data above the number of edit text fields the colour is changing. But i don't want this kind of result.

Please help me with this.

Thank you.
[Here is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwVqZ.png)

Comment: It would better if you add your code here.

Comment: please edit your question with your code.